# Create flexible recurring payment profile in Paypal

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

Is there anyway to create a flexible recurring payment profile on Paypal?

Something like this:

On the first month, there's no charge for the user.
From the second to the fifth month, there's a charge of $5.9.
From the sixth to the seventh month, there's a charge of $7.9.
From the ninth month and so on, there's a charge of $9.9.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, you can have two "trial" periods before you apply the "regular" period:

[Subscriptions and Recurring Payments Variables](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-subscriptions-outside)

[Subscriptions Introduction](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/xcl/rec/subscr-intro-outside)

So, you could have the initial free trial period ("`period1`"), then a trial period for $5.9 ("`period2`") and then the regular period ("`period3`"). Per the documentation, I think you will have to organize your payments like this. In other words, there is a limit on the number  of trial periods you can have.